# Batch Polygonize rasters into shp file using gdal_polygonize.py but no result?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, gdal, polygonize

I'm trying to use and recreate this code from [Using GDAL polygonize from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214726)

```
import subprocess, glob

script = "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py"
for raster in glob.glob("/data/brent/GAUP/Jul21_17-Apr27_18_results/imp_malaybalay/comp/*.tif"):
    outshp = raster[:-4] + ".shp"
    subprocess.call(["python", script, raster, "-f", "shp", outshp])
```

The only difference is that I am specifying an ESRI shapefile format as an output vector type (the link above used GeoJSON instead).

After I run the code, there were no results in my output folder. Is there something I missed out?

I also tried this [code](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#polygonize-a-raster-band). However, I don't have any idea on how to edit the code in a batch processing form.

Comment: Try subprocess.Popen to return an object you can poll for error messages.. it's possible the process has errors you can't see. The driver for shapefiles is -f "ESRI Shapefile" so you might need to change your list to ["python", script, raster, "-f", "\"ESRI Shapefile\"", outshp].. or not, OGR will try to guess based on your file extension if -f is omitted. If you run python followed by a script in your shell does that work for you? In Windows I would omit the "python" because the script is associated with python.exe.

Comment: Hello, I changed the "shp" into "ESRI Shapefile" from the subprocess. call line. Maybe you can edit my code and accept it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If my comment has helped you come to an answer feel free to answer your own question with your updated code.. I don't know much about the Linux (or is it Unix) operating system you're using so I'd be interested to see what works for you.

Comment: It is documented in http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html how to define the output format. The list of the short format names is in http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by [Michael Stimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15054/michael-stimson) from the comments, here's the answer for my own question:

```
import subprocess, glob

script = "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py"
for raster in glob.glob("/data/brent/GAUP/Jul21_17-Apr27_18_results/imp_malaybalay/comp/*.tif"):
    outshp = raster[:-4] + ".shp"
    subprocess.call(["python", script, raster, "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", outshp])
```